# What is the docker hub registry url for an docker image

Tags: docker

What is the docker hub full registry url for pulling docker images.

I would like to get url in the format:
[registry-url]/[namespace]/[image]:[tag]

Answer (score 25):

`[registry-url]` in your syntax defaults to `docker.io`.

`[namespace]` defaults to `library`.

`[tag]` defaults to `latest`.

Docker calls the combination of `[registry-url]/[namespace]/[image]` a *repository*, which comes up occasionally.

So, if you `docker pull mysql`, that image name is identical to `docker.io/library/mysql:latest`.

(Note that this isn't a "real" URL, and in the general case there's no single HTTP URL or Web page that maps to a specific Docker image.)

Comment: This reference is worth mentioning. https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/reference/normalize.go

Comment: The test cases for this are in TestParseRepositoryInfo in distribution/reference//normalize_test.go : https://github.com/distribution/reference/blob/main/normalize_test.go https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adistribution/reference%20TestParseRepositoryInfo&type=code

The terminology in the tests is `RemoteName, FamiliarName, FullName, AmbiguousName, Domain`.

Answer (score 0):

2023:

I'm trying to use docker hub image in vscode dev containers, and I didn't need to add `/library` as the accepted answer suggested. Something like this worked for me:

```yaml
// devcontainer.json

"image": "docker.io/ubuntu:latest"
"image": "docker.io/node:20"
"image": "docker.io/denoland/deno:latest"
"image": "docker.io/oven/bun:latest"
```

Note that some image names already contain a `/`, you just treat the whole thing including `/` as the image name.